# Query both DBPedia and Wikidata at the same time?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

Is there a way to query both DBPedia and Wikidata at the same time? 
Like any way to query all the people in DBPedia and Wikidata at the same time?

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

{ SELECT ?person WHERE { ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 } limit 100 }
UNION 
{ SELECT * { ?person a dbo:Person } }
```

Try [here](http://yasgui.org/#query=PREFIX+wd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E+%0APREFIX+wdt%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+%0A%0A%7B+SELECT+%3Fperson+WHERE+%7B+%3Fperson+wdt%3AP31+wd%3AQ5+%7D+limit+100+%7D%0AUNION+%0A%7B+SELECT+*+%7B+%3Fperson+a+dbo%3APerson+%7D+%7D%0A&contentTypeConstruct=text%2Fturtle&contentTypeSelect=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fbigdata%2Fnamespace%2Fwdq%2Fsparql&requestMethod=GET&tabTitle=Query&headers=%7B%7D&outputFormat=table)

Comment: Federated SPARQL queries is the way to go, see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I got it! @AKSW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AKSW I got the answer to my question.

The Federated SPARQL queries would do the trick:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?person WHERE { 
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {?person a dbo:Person }
  SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 }
} LIMIT 100
```

try [here](http://yasgui.org/#query=PREFIX+wd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E+%0APREFIX+wdt%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+%0A%0ASELECT+%3Fperson+WHERE+%7B+%0A++SERVICE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql%3E+%7B%3Fperson+a+dbo%3APerson+%7D%0A++SERVICE+%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E+%7B+%3Fperson+wdt%3AP31+wd%3AQ5+%7D%0A%7D+LIMIT+100+%0A%0A&contentTypeConstruct=text%2Fturtle&contentTypeSelect=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fabs.270a.info%2Fsparql&requestMethod=GET&tabTitle=Query&headers=%7B%7D&outputFormat=table)